# Handle multiple lists scroll in same view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

We have 2 `List`s side by side in an `HStack`.

One of them interacts with the `NavigationBar` while the other does not!

How can we achieve the same behavior for all scrollables like lists?

[image: Demo]

---

###### Demo code

```
    NavigationView {
        HStack {
            List(1...100, id: \.self) { _ in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            }
            List(1...100, id: \.self) { _ in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).frame(width: 100, height: 50)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("title")
    }
```

<sub>**Note**: All of them should interact with the bars preferably</sub>

Comment: Only the last list seems to interact (tested with 3 list). May be be a bug to signal to Apple.